# Maven Release from Tagged Release Candidate or Branch

Tags: svn, maven

Consider the following scenario: I have a project being developed using `maven` as build tool and `svn` or some other tool for version control.

At some point I decide that it is "probably" ready for release and I set an `svn` tag to mark it as `release candidate`

```
+ Trunk (0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
|
+----------------------------+ Branch "release-candidate" (0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
|                            | (goes to QA for testing)
+ Trunk (0.0.2-SNAPSHOT)     | 
| (development continues)    + Tag "release-0.0.1" (0.0.1)
....                           (deploy this revision)
```

At this point I need to update the `pom.xml` with the new development version.
The `release-candidate` keeps the snapshot version until the QA is done with testing and declares the release ready. Only then will the actual release + deploy be performed on the tag/branch.

Development can continue in the trunk while the release-candidate is being tested.

Can this 2-step release scenario be realized with maven builds? Is the `release` plugin enough for this or do I need others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven Release Plugin is a de facto standard for releasing Maven projects and it forces some concrete workflow for this. As I see, you have pretty different assumptions, but if you'll try to fit into Maven's convention here, Maven Release Plugin would do all work here.

First of all, `release:branch` goal can help you in creating some version-line branch while bumping version in `trunk` ready to new development. However, in my opinion it's definetelly not a good idea to share this branch name (`release-candidate` here) for every next release. Rather a standard way here is doing kind of release branch per release, where stuff is polished a little before the actual, final release. So the branch name `0.0.1` for example would be OK. And by the way, `release:branch` goal updates `<scm />` tag in POM to point on just created branch, so using shared branch is - once more - not a good idea.

After polishing  your release candidate you can do an actual release using pretty standard `release:prepare` and `release:perform` calls **from branch**, as usual in Maven. That creates tag, deploy stuff, etc.

And now, if you really want to have this branch name fixed (because of testers' need or something) you can always use `svn:externals` thing and updates `release-candidate` alias to always point on current release candidate branch.

Comment: I was using the fixed release-candidate branch for a jenkins job actually. I like the idea of using this as an alias. Thanks.